# Cannot call method 'push' of undefined

Tags: mvvm, knockout.js

I had this working in a fiddle just fine (which I can't find now), but when I moved it to VS2012 I'm getting the error "Cannot call method 'push' of undefined'.

In the code below, the createItemDiv() function works great and creates the UI elements.  It's the line before that, showItem() which calls this.visibleItem.push() that is throwing the error.  I had a problem with this in the fiddle originally and added the "this" to fix it.  If I remove "this" as it is now, I get "visibleItem is not defined".

**viewmodel.js**

```
var dummyResults = [
    { //sample data is here }
]
var dummyItems = [
]

function VisibleItem(data) {
    var self = this;
    this.name = ko.observable(data.name);
    this.type = ko.observable(data.type);
    this.description = ko.observable("");
}

function SearchResult(data) {
    var self = this;
    this.name = ko.observable(data.name);
    this.type = ko.observable(data.type);
}

var viewModel = {
    searchResult: ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(dummyResults, function (item) {
        return new SearchResult(item);
    })),
    visibleItem: ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(dummyItems, function (item) {
        return new VisibleItem(item);
    })),
    showItem: function (item) {
        this.visibleItem.push(item);
    }
};


ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

**site.js**

```
$(document).on('click', '.result', function () {
    var item = ko.dataFor(this);
    viewModel.showItem(item);     //add item to "visibleItems" viewmodel for management
    createItemDiv(item);          //ui function to show item on screen
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized I had an old binding in my html still... will vote to close.

Comment: that is your question you can delete it, but don't just submit your solution, just to warn people not to do like you

Comment: You can't delete if other people have answered.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
var viewModel = function() {
        var self = this;
        self.searchResult = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(dummyResults, function (item) {
            return new SearchResult(item);
        })),
        self.visibleItem = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(dummyItems, function (item) {
            return new VisibleItem(item);
        })),
        self.showItem = function (item) {
            self.visibleItem.push(item);
        }
    };
```

Comment: Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: searchResult is not defined;
Bindings value: foreach: searchResult